# Firefox can't find the file at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/export.php

Tags: backup

I have a huge 1.6 GB MYSQL database on my wamp local server.

I want to shift this database to another computer, so in phpmyadmin, when I export the database and click GO for download the sql file, then it takes around 5-10 mins to load and at-last displays the error "Firefox can't find the file at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/export.php."

How can I have backup of the data?

Comment: Need an answer to this old question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to dump the contents of the database to disk instead.

Comment: when I enter this command mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > d:\abc.sql  in query window of phpmyadmin, I get following error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > d:\abc.sql' at line 1"

Comment: It's a command line program.

Comment: where to write this code, I am using windows 7 as OS

Comment: At the command line. Windows calls this "Command Prompt".